# Spring Custom OAuth Approval Page

Tags: spring, oauth

I have a problem in Spring, currently Im trying to create a custom approval page. I created a resource at /oauth/confirm_access which just shows up in my OAuth flow.
The page itself is stored inside a .jsp file and a near 1:1 copy of the default approval page (for testing purposes).

But when I click the "authorize" button, I will get redirected to the login screen, so Im guessing that my cookie might be invalid for some reason (I used SessionAttribute authorizationRequest).

I looked at the implementation of the WhitelabelApprovalEndpoint and copied this. (replaced the text with my page) and it worked.

However I need to store this page as a .jsp file.

Has anyone encountered the same issue?

Im returning the page like this:

```
@RequestMapping("/oauth/confirm_access")
public ModelAndView getAccessConfirmation(@ModelAttribute AuthorizationRequest clientAuth, Map<String, Object> model, HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
    //model specifics
    return new ModelAndView("approval", "model", model);
}
```